# Troubles with load testing results

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, load

I have troubles with load testing results. The problem is that on the Summary page the results are not displayed, i.e. "Overall Results", "Key Statistics: Top 5 Slowest Tests", "Test Results", "Transaction Results" - these sections are empty. If I go to the Detail tab - I can see all tests passed.

I am using visual studio 2010 Ultimate.
I have searched the web but have not find anything similar to my situation.

Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: What are these 'load testing results', exactly? Are they something that the IDE does?

Comment: I usually run the load test from VS (sometimes I run it from command line using mstest. It does not matter how you run it). The load test consists of one web test. The only agent and controller is my local computer. Web server and db server are both separate machines.

Comment: Having exact same issue, Controller and Agents is reporting but nothing else. Odd thing is, my other load test is reporting fine. The only difference other than the test itself is that broken one uses a plug-in to prep the database before running.

Comment: @nxm When do you exactly see the Detail's tab statistics? Are you able to see them after the load test is completed? It sounds like you don't have defined the connection string for the database where the Load Test Results need to be stored.

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem (for me at least) but have yet to find a solution. It is the plugin that i am using, it is calling a web service that does some setup before the test runs. If i remove this line from the plugin (and do the set up manually) it will give me reporting. I'll let you know if i can work out a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it...
Dont know if it's relavent to you but i had a plug in that was hooking into the Loadtest_starting event and calling a web service.

This web request seemed to be confusing the reporting.

I then found a note on the MSDN blog that read :

```
Note
If a ILoadTestPlugin implementation has code that should be run before the 
load test starts on any agent, that code should be placed in the load test
plug-in Initialize method instead of in the LoadTestStarting event handler,
because the former is guaranteed to run before the load test is started on
any agent, whereas the latter is not.
```

After moving my code out of the started even and into Initialised it worked great.
Hope it helps.